# Enable nginx module on Laravel Homestead?

Tags: nginx, laravel, vagrant

How can I install and enable the file upload and upload progress module on nginx with the Laravel Homestead box on Vagrant?

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you need to do, like it was mentioned above, is log in with ssh to your box and install the nginx-extras package.  So:

1. Got to your Homestead directory.
2. Do 'vagrant ssh'
3. Once in do 'sudo apt-get install nginx-extras'
4. Restart nginx with 'sudo service nginx restart'
5. Check for the module in the output of 'sudo nginx -V'.  Messy but you should see 'nginx-upload-progress' somewhere near the end of the output.

Comment: Thank you I'll report back, I was unaware of this package! I was thinking I had to remake the nginx installation with the modules enable within the ./configure option!

Comment: I was unaware of that package too until a few days ago while reading the book titled "Scaling PHP". In it there is an example of managing image uploads efficiently with nginx/php. Looks like a cool solution to hand off upload payloads directly to php. Currently implementing it in a project of mine that gets large amounts of attached files. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything via `ssh`. Read more detail about using ssh in Homestead at [here](http://laravel.com/docs/homestead#daily-usage).