# How to add new module to nginx in laravel homestead?

Tags: laravel, nginx, homestead

I want to add new nginx module on my homestead box:

- ngx_pagespeed
- ngx_http_gzip_module
- nginx-upload-module

I'm new in nginx. What should I do? What should I type in my after.sh?

Answer (score 0):

This question might be a duplicate of the question below:

**Enable nginx module on Laravel Homestead?**

[Enable nginx module on Laravel Homestead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255310/enable-nginx-module-on-laravel-homestead)